# How to get rid of an enumeral mismatch error in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

In the book that I found there's a code computing a square root of a given number, but the code doesn't compile. There is a lot of errors when instantiating the template. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template
<int N, int LO=1, int HI=N> class Sqrt {
public:
    enum { mid = (LO+HI+1)/2 };

    enum { result = (N<mid*mid) ? Sqrt<N,LO,mid-1>::result : Sqrt<N,mid,HI>::result };
};

template<int N, int M> class Sqrt<N,M,M> {
public:
    enum { result=M };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Sqrt<5>::result << std::endl;
}
```

and many of the warnings are

```
enumeral mismatch in conditional expression 'Sqrt<5,1,1>::< anonymous enum> vs 'Sqrt<5,2,2>::< anonymous enum>' [-Wenum-compare]
```

as I tested later this warning is not critical, for example in the code

```
class a {
public:
    enum {test = 0};
};

class b {
public:
    enum {test = 1};
};

class c {
public:
    enum {test = 2 < 3 ? a::test : b::test};
};

int main()
{
    int v = c::test;
}
```

I get the same warning, but the code compiles. My confusion is caused because if I place the '-Wenum-compare' in compiler options, the first code compiles. What is the real problem here?

Comment: I've never seen an enum used that way.  In my experience, it's usually used to define constants, something like:
enum
{
   ONE: 1,
   TWO: 2
};

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON It is a common trick in template meta programming as enum values are compile time constants and can be used in templates.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks very much for your response.

Comment: What compiler are you using.  Even with the warning g++ still compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3348a5e6e00c6e3e

Comment: @NathanOliver I use code::blocks

Comment: With which compiler? code::blocks is just an IDE.

Comment: @NathanOliver The default one I guess? The output message is mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\p.exe obj\Debug\p.o

Comment: The obvious answer: don't use `enum`s for this type of thing. Instead use compile-time constants, i.e. `static const int` or `static constexpr int` (since C++11). But in C++11, you don't need any template magic, simply define a `constexpr` function and use it at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `enum`, you can use `static constexpr int`.

```
template <int N, int LO=1, int HI=N> struct Sqrt {
    static constexpr int mid = (LO+HI+1)/2;
    static constexpr int result = (N<mid*mid) ? Sqrt<N,LO,mid-1>::result : Sqrt<N,mid,HI>::result;
};

template<int N, int M> struct Sqrt<N,M,M> {
    static constexpr int result=M;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the warning you can cast the enums into their integer values.  This means you have two integers instead of two different enumerations.

```
template
<int N, int LO=1, int HI=N> class Sqrt {
public:
    enum { mid = (LO+HI+1)/2 };

    enum { result = (N<mid*mid) ? static_cast<int>(Sqrt<N,LO,mid-1>::result) : static_cast<int>(Sqrt<N,mid,HI>::result) };
};

template<int N, int M> class Sqrt<N,M,M> {
public:
    enum { result=M };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Sqrt<5>::result << std::endl;
}
```

Will compile without warning.  As for why you get these warnings even though it compiles see: [Why do I get an error when directly comparing two enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772839/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-directly-comparing-two-enums)